# Implementation of social sharing button in rails 3 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In my web app where I'm using rails 3 code to generate a link that I want to be shared across various social media. Now I found a simple solution for this without using 'OmniAuth' to do this. The site is [here](https://www.addthis.com)

Now If you login you will see a code like this.

```
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_pinterest_pinit"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-50effbad1fc26ade"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

So I added the following code to my site. So it worked fine. But after login to any of these options provided I found that it's actually copying the name of my application(it's ok) and then it's also copying the link in my page which is available automatically in my clipboard is being copied. But the problem is it's adding some extra information before my generated link. For example the link becomes:

```
http://localhost:3000/linkbunches/4vlvmm#.UPALKv3f-cw.gmail
```

whereas it should be like

```
http://localhost:3000/linkbunches/4vlvmm
```

So Anybody has any Idea how to solve this issue because I didn't find anything in their site to solve this problem.
If anybody can suggests any alternate solution to implement this functionality it would be nice.

Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is added by addthis to keep track of your referral traffic and provide you with analytics if you want to have.

If you are looking for some thing without tracking, try [shareaholic](http://shareaholic.com/), [loginradius](http://www.loginradius.com) and other services.